# Как можно сделать запрос к сайту с фейкового айпи?

Tags: python

Делаю скрипт с использованием модуля socket. Мне необходимо сделать простой запрос к сайту ,но с фейкового айпи. Напишите пример того, как это сделать  в коде

Comment: Это технически невозможно, интернет-провайдеры просто не пропустят запросы с фейковым айпи

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Используйте прокси.

   ```
   r = s.post(URL, data=data, headers=headers, proxies=proxies)
   ```

Где переменная `proxies` - словарь.

```
proxies = {
'http': 'xxx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxx',
'https': 'xxx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxx'}
```

2. Заменяете User-Agent. По стандарту он 'python-requests' - многие сайты блокируют.
3. Если берете прокси из общего доступа, то он уже может быть заблокированным (на самом деле это довольно часто). Берите сразу большое кол-во прокси и пробуйте перебирать их примерно так:

   ```
   proxies = []
   for proxy in proxies:
   response = requests.get(proxies=proxy)
   if response.status_code == requests.codes['ok']:
   break

   response.text
   ```

Взято из [взаимосвязанного вопроса](https://qna.habr.com/q/649336)

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/633106)

Comment: @0xdb, поправил

Comment: Прокси используют вполне реальные айпи, не фейковые.

Comment: @andreymal, что тогда можно понимать под фейковым айпи, как не свой?